# how to make a Delaunay triangulation in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, triangulation

So I'm trying to make my own Delaunay triangulation maker fist I need to make triangular in my code. I do this by finding 3 obj and adding them to a list. Know there are two things I do not know how to do first I need to see if that obj is on the list next. I need to do that for every obj.

```
[System.Serializable]
public class tringle
{
    public GameObject GameOBJ_0, GameOBJ_1, GameOBJ_2;

    private Vector3 pos_0;
    private Vector3 pos_1;
    private Vector3 pos_2;
    public Vector3 midpoint;
    public void SetGameOBJ_0(GameObject setOBj_0)
    {
        GameOBJ_0 = setOBj_0;
    }
    public void SetGameOBJ_1(GameObject setOBj_1)
    {
        GameOBJ_1 = setOBj_1;
    }
    public void SetGameOBJ_2(GameObject setOBj_2)
    {
        GameOBJ_2 = setOBj_2;
    }
    public void SetPos()
    {
        pos_0= GameOBJ_0.transform.localPosition;
        pos_1= GameOBJ_1.transform.localPosition;
        pos_2= GameOBJ_2.transform.localPosition;
        FindMidPoint();
    }
    public void FindMidPoint()
    {
        midpoint = new Vector3((pos_0.x + pos_1.x + pos_2.x)/3,0, (pos_0.z + pos_1.z + pos_2.z) / 3);
    }
}
```

and

```
    foreach (GameObject room in Rooms)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Rooms.Length / 3; i++)
        {
            if (TRINGLE[i].GameOBJ_0 != room && TRINGLE[i].GameOBJ_1 != room && TRINGLE[i].GameOBJ_2 != room)
            {
                foreach (tringle item in TRINGLE)
                {
                    if (!TRINGLE.Contains(item)) TRINGLE.Add(item);
                }
            }
        }
    }`
```

Comment: What is your question exactly?

Comment: Also you iterate `tringle item in TRINGLE` and within the loop check whether `TRINGLE.Contains(item)` .. this will of course be the case for each and every `item` since you are iterating the `TRINGLE` ... Makes little sense to me

Answer (score 0):

```
 public GameObject GameOBJ_0, GameOBJ_1, GameOBJ_2;
private Vector3 pos_0;
private Vector3 pos_1;
private Vector3 pos_2;
public Vector3 midpoint;
public void SetGameOBJ_0(GameObject setOBj_0)
{
    GameOBJ_0 = setOBj_0;

}
public void SetGameOBJ_1(GameObject setOBj_1)
{
    GameOBJ_1 = setOBj_1;

}
public void SetGameOBJ_2(GameObject setOBj_2)
{
    GameOBJ_2 = setOBj_2;
    SetPos();
}
public void SetPos()
{
    pos_0= GameOBJ_0.transform.localPosition;
    pos_1= GameOBJ_1.transform.localPosition;
    pos_2= GameOBJ_2.transform.localPosition;
    FindMidPoint();
}
public void FindMidPoint()
{
    midpoint = new Vector3((pos_0.x + pos_1.x + pos_2.x)/3,0, (pos_0.z + pos_1.z + pos_2.z) / 3);
}


 void Update()
{
    foreach (GameObject room in Rooms)
    {
        if(i < triglenuber)
        {
           foreach (tringle item in TRINGLE)
           {
                if (!OBJPos.Contains(room))
                {
                   
                    if (TRINGLE[i].GameOBJ_0 == null)
                    {
                        OBJPos.Add(room);
                        TRINGLE[i].SetGameOBJ_0(room);
                    }
                    else if (TRINGLE[i].GameOBJ_1 == null)
                    {
                        OBJPos.Add(room);
                        TRINGLE[i].SetGameOBJ_1(room);
                    }
                    else if (TRINGLE[i].GameOBJ_2 == null)
                    {
                        OBJPos.Add(room);
                        TRINGLE[i].SetGameOBJ_2(room);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        i++;
                    }
                }
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).